# Error en Intent

Tags: android

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en AndroidStudio que consiste en consumir ciertos xml desde internet y cargarlos en CardViews y utilizando RecyclerView. Al momento de presionar en la imagen del Card, deseo que se abra el articulo en una ventana dentro de un fragment, pero me figura un error.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

Dejo además URL de proyecto en GIT para aclarar cualquier duda.
https://github.com/rvargassanhueza/ReadXmlFromInternet

Saludos y muchas gracias.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
Context c;
ArrayList<Article> articles;
Activity activity;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Article> articles, Activity activity) {
    this.c = c;
    this.articles = articles;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Article article=articles.get(position);
    String title=article.getTitle();
    //String desc=article.getDescription();
    String dateFecha=article.getTsFecha();
    String dateHora=article.getTsHora();
    String imageUrl=article.getImageUrl();

    holder.titleTxt.setText(title);
    holder.dateFechaTxt.setText(dateFecha);
    holder.dateHoraTxt.setText(dateHora);

    String baseUrl = "http://www.google.cl";//ejemplo
    String cadenaUrl = baseUrl+imageUrl;

   // Log.i("valor total cadena",": "+cadenaUrl);
  Picasso.with(c).load(cadenaUrl).into(holder.img);


    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PictureDetailActivity.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

                Explode explode = new Explode();
                explode.setDuration(1000);
                //si estuvieramos en una actividad no sería necesario agregar activity.getWindow, solo getWindow
                //activity.getWindow()

                //como personalizamos la duración de la transición(el objeto Explode), debemos colocar el nombre de la clase instanciada,
                // .setExitTransition(explode);
                // de lo contrario solo sería .setExitTransition(new Explode()); y toma los valores por defecto de Explode.

                activity.getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
                activity.startActivity(intent, ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,v,activity.getString(R.string.transitonname_picture))
                        .toBundle());
            }else {

                activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return articles.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Te dice que el objeto es nulo, ¿lo has inicializado?

Comment: ¿O sea que hay que **explorar** tu proyecto en Github para tratar de adivinar donde se encuentra tu error? Android Studio tiene herramientas de depuración que indican dónde falla el código, es importante que aprendas a utilizarlas, te ayudará mucho a ti y a nosotros cuando necesites ayuda en algo concreto. ¡Venga, un poquito más de esfuerzo hombre!

Comment: y el código? porqe preguntas sin agregar código del problema

Comment: Disculpen, acabo de publicar el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

**El problema es que el contexto que usas `activity` tiene un valor null al crear un Intent**:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PictureDetailActivity.class);
```

de hecho te puedes dar cuenta que la activity que envías en realidad estas enviando un valor null (tercer parametro).

```
  rv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(c,articles,null));
```

usa el de la aplicación que esta disponible:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(c, PictureDetailActivity.class);
```

Comment: +1 me ganaste :(

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar y les comento.

Saludos.

Comment: Hice lo que me pediste, pero aún así tengo un problema.

 Process: cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial, PID: 2582
                                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window android.app.Activity.getWindow()' on a null object reference

Código actualizado en GITHub